# Can't remove event handler, adding multiple times

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a piece of code where I add a handler everytime the form is open, I'm working in visual basic, but the first time I enter the form everything works fine, but for the second time I have 2 handlers, if I enter a third I have 3 handlers and so on. I don't know why is this happenning.

Here is what I tried so far.

I have stored all my machines in another class but I'm sending to myForm to show them, but to add them I use this code:

```
    Private Sub add_machine(ByRef machine As Machine)

    RemoveHandler machine.imgBox.Click, AddressOf Me.imgBox_Click
    AddHandler machine.imgBox.Click, AddressOf Me.imgBox_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(machine.get_imgMachine)

    Private Sub imgBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        
    'Some code
    End Sub
```

Everytime I open the form I call the sub add_machine to add dinamically my machines, as you can see I send them `ByRef` to simplify my code I tried to put that `RemoveHandler` since I'm sending `ByRef` to avoid having more than one handler, but it's not working please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `machine` passed to this function is the same as in previous call? If not, this will not work. You need to unsubscribe from previous `machine` instance.

Comment: I think is the same `machine` because I have a button that calls this form, my main form is always open and that is where I store the machines, how would I know if is not the same instance.

Comment: You tagged this as VBA, but maybe you mean Visual Basic? Have you taken a look at:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, DONT pass machine ByRef. You are not returning a new object. Please read this link for more information on when you should use what [Byval vs ByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx)

Second, add your handlers during form load (or initialization) and remove them in form closing. This will help ensure you are working with references to the same object.

Comment: I didn't think in that way, I feel so stupid right now thanks